# Video rendering on Windows when DXVA-HD is not available

Tags: directx, directx-11, windows-10-desktop

Let me preface that I am not an expert on Windows' various video APIs, which is partly why I'm asking this question.

Our application is using DXVA-HD APIs to output video on a surface in our .NET 4.6 WPF application. It works on Intel and nVidia devices, however we've found AMD graphics devices are not supporting DXVA-HD and our app just shows a blank surface. (We've tested on HD4550, HD8970M, 270X, Radeon VII, 5700XT)

What is the recommended way to show accelerated video (on windows 10, we've discontinued support for 8.1 and below), if DXVA-HD isn't supported?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that mentioned AMD GPUs have no support for DXVA-HD, and this basically invalidates the question itself. Also various Windows Media Foundation samples would prove that these systems have full capabilities to decode video with hardware acceleration. This is what you can use instead of DXVA-HD (Media Foundation would leverage DXVA internally in an efficient way).

Comment: It's true, they don't support DXVA-HD. Querying these devices they return not supported. They do support DXVA2, AMD just chooses not to support the -HD extensions in their drivers. It's bizarre but true when you google DXVA-HD and Radeon you'll find lots of people's dxdiag logs reporting -HD isn't supported.

Comment: Out of curiosity what sort of processing you are doing with DXVA-HD?

Comment: You can try using Direct3D 11 Video APIs instead, which should be supported by AMD on Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/direct3d-11-video-apis

Comment: @RomanR. Scaling, YUV to RGB, colour space translation, and some tiling of multiple sources into a single video. It appears that we simply picked a dead end API by choosing DXVA-HD. All these operations are available in DXVA2, it's just more awkward to use. Or, we can go with D3D11 Video API.

Comment: Yes, [Direct3D 11 Video Processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11videodevice-createvideoprocessor) are doing pretty much the same and in uniform way across GPU vendors.